# How to get Instance of Any class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, singleton, instance

I have following code using which I am manually getting instance of class as per request came for processing.

Suppose I have one Interface which will be implemented by each class :

```
interface fooBar{

}
```

and following are class in which I am implementing that interface and each class have different body as per request :

```
class AddFoo implements fooBar{

}
class DeleteFoo implements fooBar{

}
class AddBar implements fooBar{

}
class DeleteBar implements fooBar{

}
```

following is class that return instance manually as per request :

```
class ProcessAllRequest{

    @Autowired
    private AddFoo addfoo;
    @Autowired
    private DeleteFoo deletefoo;

    public fooBar fooBargetProcessor(fooBar f){
        if(f.getClass.equals(AddFoo.class)){
            return addfoo;
        }else if(f.getClass.equals(DeleteFoo.class)){
            return deletefoo;
        }else return null;
    }
}
```

I have also tried like `return new AddFoo();` but that give me null instance so I have used `Autowired` and work perfectly.

now when I will call `fooBargetProcessor(fooBar f)` in any class to process request it will give me instance of that class as per request.

So my question is that is there any method so I can get instance automatically without `@Autowired` and other static data in `fooBargetProcessor()` method ?

> **UPDATE :**

I have called this method in other method name `ProcessRequest()`.

And for all I have made commands and mapped each with form data using ModelMapper.

like :

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

AddFoo f = mapper.map(form, AddFoo.class);
ProcessRequest(f);
```

and in `ProcessRequest() i have called fooBargetProcessor()` method.

**Sample class code :**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/foo")
    public class Foo extends BaseApi{
        @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        String add(@RequestBody AddFooForm form){

            ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
            AddFoo f = mapper.map(form, AddFoo.class);
            ProcessRequest(f);

            return "Hello";
        }
    }
```

now as per request to the /api/foo/ it will pass to various method like if POST then add and PUT then update and if DELETE then delete methods like so on, to explain full flow and code of my project is somewhat impossible because it takes so much time to make first skeleton.

Now as per request came in Controller I have to just Map data as per request and called method `ProcessRequest()` in that controller class.

Anyone know about it then please give me guidance.

Comment: I don't know how @Autowired works, but shouldn't there be a return type for your function fooBargetProcessor ?

Comment: Your code won't run (missing return type) and I fail to see what your code intends to do.

Comment: Yes I haven't provide return type in this code but actually all have return types so it will run and I want just singleton instance of class.

Comment: Okay, so you want to use a specific instance of each class, even though you have other instances that exist (so it's not a singleton really). I would like to know more about your design, and how you came to this idea?

Comment: Sir I have Updated Question with other flow and data that how actually my code works.

Comment: @Kayaman - No it's a singleton, I haven't created object of that class anywhere in application. I have just used it here only..

Comment: Your code is wrong and confusing. You're passing a Class object into the method, Class object doesn't implement "fooBar" so the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: My application is already running sir, it's so complex to explain you so you are telling like that, I want only the instance as per method argument. I have tried ParameterizedType and other thing but not working. Sir can you told me that without @Autowired can I return instance of class and also without new ? Is there any other option for that ? I am stuck in this situation because like AddFoo and so on I have near about 300 classes so I can't write it manually in if condition and also it's wrong concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some code change I have removed `class ProcessAllRequest` and the place where I am calling it's method `fooBargetProcessor(fooBar f)` I have written this code and works fine for me, now I have got instance of any operation / class at run time.

Feeling so good because first time I have done this type of code and works fine.

Code :

First I have `Autowired` application context in class like :

`@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;`

then in `ProcessRequest()` method I have write this code for to get instance :

```
String processorName = Introspector.decapitalize(f.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Processor");
ICommandProcessor processor = (ICommandProcessor) context.getBean(processorName);
```

Here `f` is `fooBar` object.

So short and simple code, have removed so much un necessary code.

Thank You All.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply get all of your `fooBar`, why not simply ask Spring for an array or collection of them?  Then, in your `fooBargetProcessor()` you could do something like:

```
@Autowired
private List<fooBar> processors;

public <T extends fooBar> T getProcessor(Class<T> type) {
   fooBar processor = null;
   for (fooBar p : processors) {
      if (p.getClass().equals(type)) {
         processor = p;
         break;
      }
   }
   return processor;
}
```

**Caveats:** This was typed from memory, so some testing and code cleanup might be necessary.

Basically, we ask Spring to give us all `fooBar`s in a `List`.  You will need to have the `fooBar` instances tagged with `@Component` or something so that Spring will find them.  Spring should find all instances and wire them into the `List` (see docs for [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)).  The method then uses Java Generics to figure out which type you want, then loops through the `List` to find it.  You could use a `Set` instead of a `List` to guarantee uniqueness of the `fooBar` objects.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for the answer and see my own answer. I have tried something new and that's working fine for me. This is something different but this short code have done all for me.